# Bucle "for" procesa todos los archivos pero sólo muestra el resultado del último archivo procesado

Tags: python, linux, bash, bucle-for, bucles

Hice este simple script para que procese x cantidad de archivos. El script llama a otro script escrito en python llamado "selectionStats.py".

Este es el script

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=./*fasta
for f in  $FILES
do
  echo "Processing $f file..."
  a="${f%.*}"
  selectionStats.py -a $f > $a.txt   
done
```

Los ficheros son del tipo:

- africa_final_remove_new.93.fasta
- africa_final_remove_new.94.fasta

Sin embargo, no obtengo el resultado para cada archivo procesado, solo obtengo el resultado del ultimo archivo que procesa.

Este tipo de script suelo utilizarlos con otros programas sin ningún problema, pero en este caso no cumple su objetivo. También, intenté con parallel y obtengo el mismo resultado.

Gracias

Comment: Es un problema de bash, no de Python

Comment: Lo probé en mi máquina y funciona como se espera. Curioso.

Comment: Lo que he notado es que, se genera un archivo de salida llamado: selectionStats.txt el cual se sobrescribe hasta dejar el resultado del último archivo procesado.

Comment: No creo que selectionStats.py esté alterando las variables de ambiente. Para salir del paso, probastes con ">>$a.txt"?

Comment: Continua ocurriendo lo mismo.

Comment: Mueve la línea del `echo` a después de asignar la variable `a` y añade `$a.txt` al `echo` para ver así cuál es el nombre del fichero generado y verificar si te van saliendo nombres de ficheros diferentes o siempre el mismo (como parece que es lo que está pasando). Revisa también que el script python esté volcando el resultado en la salida estándar, no vaya a ser que sea ese script el que está creando el fichero de resultados.

Comment: Hice lo que comentaste y siempre es el mismo nombre.  Revisare el script

Comment: Mire el script python y este genera el archivo llamado selectionStats.txt

Comment: ¿la salida debe ser cada vez en un fichero diferente? Por otra parte, guardar en `FILES` no es necesario, puedes decir directamente `for file in *fasta`

Comment: Efectivamente debería dar cada vez una archivo diferente, que lo hace, pero sin resultados almacenados en estos. Y si continua generando selectionStats.txt  con el resultado del ultimo archivo procesado.

Comment: bueno entonces deberías determinar qué nombre quieres que tenga el fichero de salida (por cierto, para responder a alguien en comentarios usa `@nombre`, por ejemplo @Alex)

Comment: @fedorqui , puedes poner un ejemplo para que me quede mas claro. Gracias

Comment: @Alex es que depende del nombre que quieras que tenga el fichero y el nombre que tienen los *fasta. ¿Podrías dar un ejemplo de eso?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar'  así estan mi archivos: africa_final_remove_new.93.fasta
africa_final_remove_new.94.fasta
africa_final_remove_new.95.fasta
africa_final_remove_new.96.fasta
africa_final_remove_new.97.fasta
africa_final_remove_new.98.fasta
africa_final_remove_new.99.fasta
africa_final_remove_new.9.fasta

Comment: Pues a="${f%.*}" Te debería funcionar, haz como comenta @abulafia y añade echos para ver cómo se resuelve

Comment: voto para cerrar pues no se puede reproducir el error con la evidencia mostrada